# Does Postgres read blocks sequentially, even if a disk is high-latency?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, amazon-web-services

I'm using Postgres on AWS EBS, when running a query that uses a bitmap heap scan and a bitmap index scan, the execution time seems proportional to the number of "heap blocks" read, as shown by the EXPLAIN ANALYZE (I've not 100% verified this). Because EBS is networked attached storage, it has a high (~1ms) latency, but a high throughput/bandwidth, meaning Postgres wouldn't be taking full advantage of the disk.

Is it the case that when reading from Disk postgres queries blocks/pages sequentially?

Comment: When doing a sequential scan, yes. When doing any sort of index scan, it's unlikely. (It's not impossible, if your indexed expression happens to match the on-disk sequence of rows, but if your query were broad enough to touch many contiguous blocks, the planner would probably have picked a seqscan plan instead anyway)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of bitmap heap scan, it can issue async block reads.  This is controlled by effective_io_concurrency.